# Is there a faster way to write to stdout?

Tags: go, io

I am implementing Unix commands in Go as a way to learn more about Go.  I have read some articles where people have implemented yes in various and gotten up to 3 gig per second transfer rates.  Through trial an error I have gotten my Go implementation to around 1.5 gig per second:

```
package main

import (
        f "fmt"
        "os"
        s "strings"
)

const bufsize = 1024 * 64

func main() {
        atom := "y\n"

        if len(os.Args) > 1 {
                atom = s.Join(os.Args[1:], " ") + "\n"
        }

        buf := s.Repeat(atom, bufsize / len(atom))

        for {
                f.Print(buf)
        }
}
```

Is there a lower level/faster function to print to stdout?

Comment: Not sure if this is faster but did you try `io.Copy` with `os.Stdout` as its first arguemnt and your `buf` value converted into `[]byte` and then using that with `bytes.NewReder` as the second argument to `io.Copy`? E.g.; `io.Copy(os.Stdout, bytes.NewReader([]byte(buf)))` but maybe do the conversion outside of the loop?

Comment: Just call `os.Stdout.Write()` with a big prepared slice, the least overhead.

Comment: @icza using os.Stdout.Write(buf) I am still limited to around 1.5 gig per second (but I was able to reduce the buffer size to 16K instead of 64K)

Comment: @mkopriva I am seeing similar performance for that as the os.Stdout.Write() solution, which is the same as mine (but mine has a larger buffer)

Comment: The "3gig per second transfer rates" implementations, did you test those implementations on your machine as well or you've only read about them in the articles? I'm not doubting what those articles say, I just wonder if your machine is as performant as those used by the authors of those articles.

Comment: @mkopriva I am starting to wonder the same thing. Or if they were doing things I am not.

Comment: So far the best performance I have gotten is using syscall.Write(1, buf) with a 512K buffer (anything bigger and it slows down again). And that was only marginally better than the os.Stdout.Write(buf) with a 16K buffer.

Comment: @mkopriva Compiling some C code the the author claimed gets 10 GB per second on his/her machine yields a slower result than even my Go code. The Go code is faster than the stock Ubuntu yes (which the author was also claiming was 10 GB per second).  So I guess it is fast enough.

Comment: @Chas.Owens interesting that the C version is slower, probably something to do with how its implemented... anyway I'm glad you've got it sorted out.

Comment: I'm guessing you are doing something like `yes | pv --rate`. I think Linux pipes have a 64k buffer by default, which is probably why that's the fastest. Maybe you could adjust that? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11946/how-big-is-the-pipe-buffer#11954

Comment: Thanks @Chas.Owens for [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47121464/is-there-a-faster-way-to-write-to-stdout#comment81194890_47121464) ... I got best performance with 1M buffer size using `os.Stdout.Write(buf)`